# Excel Conditionally Join Text Without Array Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel 365:

In Table 1 and Table 2, there are lists of names. Each row in Table 1 and Table 2 has only one unique name.

In Table 3, there are three columns consisting of (Column A) a list of names from Table 1 and Table 2, (Column B) types of aliases (a/k/a, d/b/a, f/d/b/a, f/k/a, n/k/a, o/b/o, pseud.), and (Column C) different alias names for different people. Each row in Table 3 only has one alias and there could be in Table 3 multiple rows containing multiple aliases for one person in Table 1 or Table 2.

Some names in Table 1 and Table 2 have aliases while other names in Table 1 and Table 2 do not. Some names in Table 1 and Table 2 have multiple aliases and sometimes names from Table 1 and Table 2 will have no aliases.

I am looking for a formula, without using an array formula, that in a column in Table 1 and Table 2, will add any and all aliases identified in Table 3 for the given name, along with the abbreviation.

For example:

Jon Doe in Table 1 may have aliases in Table 3 of alias type a/k/a Ted and f/k/a Robert Smith. I would want a column in Table 1 where, for Jon Doe's row, the formula would yield the result, "Jon Doe a/k/a Ted f/k/a Robert Smith".

How do I write a formula like this?

=textjoin would be the logical formula but I need something that is conditional like =textjoinif without an array formula--i.e., without entering the formula with control, shift, enter because those formulas are very slow.

Thanks for your help.

TABLE 1

| Name | NameWithAlias |
| --- | --- |
| Jon Doe | Jon Doe a/k/a Ted f/k/a Robert Smith |

TABLE 2 (different data, but same format of data as TABLE 1)

TABLE 3

| Name | Type | Alias |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jon Doe | a/k/a | Ted |
| Jon Doe | f/k/a | Robert Smith |

I am looking for a formula to generate the NameWithAlias in TABLE 1 without using an array formula--i.e., no control, shift, enter.

Thanks

Comment: What's your Excel version? What kind of formula(s) have you tried so far? With what results? Please don't answer in a comment, update your question instead.

Comment: Please post some sample data (in tabular format) with desired output. It's difficult to understand your question in current form

Comment: maybe something like `=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the values in column 1 in Tables 1 and 2 as input to the following formula. Substitute their references where I have "E1":

```
=E1&" "&TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B1:B4&"|"&C1:C4,A1:A4=E1),"|"," "))
```

If you'd like to use `ARRAYTOTEXT()`, it will put a comma between the "a/k/a" type information so you need to wrap it in another `SUBSTITUTE()` to replace commas with spaces:

```
=E1&" "&SUBSTITUTE(ARRAYTOTEXT(SUBSTITUTE(FILTER(B1:B4&"|"&C1:C4,A1:A4=E1),"|"," ")),",","")
```

Basically, `FILTER()` finds all the Table 3 items (replace the "B1:B4&"|"&C1:C4" portion with the proper references from Table 3) that match each Table 1 or 2 item (the "A1:A4=E1" portion:  replace the range reference with the Table 3 column reference).

The "|" bit added is meant to keep odd coincidences from happening. `SUBSTITUITE()` removes them from the result, putting the desired space in their places.

Then `TEXTJOIN()`, preferably, or `ARRAYTOTEXT()` if you don't mind adding the extra `SUBSTITUTE()`, will join the output of `FILTER()` (an array internally to the formula, even in older versions) into the desired form and the result is appended to the Column 1 value.

Let the Table functionality copy it down the column.

Since all this happens without `DYNAMIC` arrays, it works in the Tables. Only the `SPILL` (dynamic) aspect would not. The Table carries the formula down so {CSE} entry is not needed which matches your condition.

Even though {CSE} and `SPILL` are not used OUTSIDE the formula, all the INTERNAL arrays are carried throughout letting `FILTER()` and `TEXTJOIN()` to do their work. There'd be problems if you actually output the results in two or more steps in helper columns or Named Ranges, so this is the way to go.

Also, no need to torture yourself to get `FILTER()` to `SPILL` since it would not in a Table anyway.